# Modeling a continuous variable which can't take values between a and b

Tags: modeling, logical-constraints

Consider two binary variables $p_1$ and $p_2$. Suppose, $x$ is a continuous variable that should not take values between $a$ and $b$.

Here is my try:

$$
p_1 =1 \mbox{ if } x \le a \\
p_1 =0 \mbox{ if } x >a  \\
p_2 =1 \mbox{ if } x \ge b  \\
p_2 =0 \mbox{ if } x < b 
$$
Now what will be the final equations??
$$
p_1+p_2=1
$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to model
$$
x \le a \mbox{ or } x \ge b
$$
which you can enforce with a binary variable $p\in \{0,1\}$ and big M constraints:
\begin{align}
b - M_1p \le x&\le a +M_2(1-p) \\
\end{align}

The LHS enforces $p=0 \implies x\ge b$, while the RHS enforces $p=1 \implies x \le a$:

- if $p=0$, the constraint becomes $$ b  \le x\le a +M_2 $$
- if $p=1$, the constraint becomes $$ b - M_1 \le x \le a $$

If $x \ge 0$, you could set $M_1$ to $b$. $M_2$ is either an upper bound on $x-a$ (if available), or a large constant.

Comment: I gave you a +1, but it might be good to explicitly specify the $M$ values, especially because the best choices for $M$ are different values in the two places.

Comment: Agreed! I have specified the $M$ values for the answer to be more thorough.

Comment: Can you please share more explanation on M1 and M2

Comment: @user11940 $M_1$ and $M_2$ are "large" constants, which should be as small as possible for numerical issues (see for example this [link](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/dealing_with_big_m_constra.html)).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming $ b \lt a$ you can try

$ x + \epsilon \le b + Mp$
if $ p=0$ then $ x \lt b$, the 2nd constr becomes meaningless.

$ a+\epsilon \le x + M(1-p)$
if $p=1$ $x \gt a$, 1st constr turns meaningless & since $ b \lt a$ so $x$ cant be $[b,a]$

$M$ is a reasonably big number, maybe upper bound of $x$ and $\epsilon$ is a very small number to take care $\lt$.

Comment: your $p$ is my $1-p$

Comment: And your $(b,a)$ is @Kuifje's $(a,b)$.